# Font Face not taking effect in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The code below should work fine, however, does not take effect.

I've defined the following in `application.rb`, `development.rb`, `production.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

**`fonts.scss`**:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Garamond-Pro-Italic';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/Adobe_Garamond_Pro_Italic.ttf') format('ttf');
}
```

**`buttons.scss`**:

```
.menu-button
{
    font-family: 'Garamond-Pro-Italic', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: `config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts.scss')` change this line as mentioned

Comment: Thanks, still not working though.

Comment: use asset-url("/fonts/Adobe_Garamond_Pro_Italic.ttf") and not url, and look in your fonts.css compiled file , what path do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `fonts.scss`:

```
// First line of file:
//= depend_on_asset "Garamond-Pro-Italic.ttf"

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Garamond-Pro-Italic';
  src: url(font-path('Adobe_Garamond_Pro_Italic.ttf')) format('truetype');
}
```

In application.scss:

```
//= require <path_to_scss_file>
```

You should only need the following line in application.rb:
`config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')`

Of course, make sure `Adobe_Garamond_Pro_Italic.ttf` is actually in the `app/assets/fonts/` directory and not vendor, lib, or public.

If that doesn't work post any asset 404 errors you get in your dev console along with the compiled fonts.scss file.